# Problems creating Tables from command line Mysql

Tags: mysql, csv, csh, load-data-infile

When I type in the code into the Terminal it creates the Database but doesn't create the Table.
When I type in use "locations" then "Show TABLES" it tells me that no Tables were created.
This code should create a Database and the Table then import the csv file into the database "locations"

Comment: After creating the database you might try using the "use" command to switch to the database before creating the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a full answer, based off of @Honeyboy's comment.

In addition to needing to `USE locations;` there are some other things to fix:

- Shell quoting wasn't really quite right.  For one thing, your existing code doesn't account for the line breaks -- it needs line continuation escapes to run as written.
- The name of the table changed between the `CREATE TABLE` statement and the `LOAD DATA` statement
- The `LOAD DATA` statement didn't ignore the header row of your tab delimited file.

```sh
mysql -u root --password=password -e \
'CREATE DATABASE locations; \
USE locations; \
CREATE TABLE location_T (number1 INT NOT NULL, \
number2 INT NOT NULL, \
number3 INT NOT NULL, \
names VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (number1)); \
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "locations.csv" \
INTO TABLE location_T FIELDS TERMINATED by "\t" \
ENCLOSED BY "\"" LINES TERMINATED BY "\n" IGNORE 1 LINES \
(number1,number2,number3,names)'
```

Comment: i am typing it in linux shell , i also type the code in csh the compiler tells me that ' " ' is unmatched. Could you also explain to me why you are using the ' \' operator?

Comment: Your original question didn't mention that, and bash is far more common.  I have now adjusted the answer for csh, but you might be interested to read about [the challenges of scripting in csh](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/).

Comment: i tried typing it in bash and csh and I always get an error : it always says 'syntax error near unexpected token `(''

Comment: This version is for csh, the other version was for bash.  Are you saying neither work in their correct shell?

Comment: yes , I tried it for bash and csh and neither works. It keeps telling me that I have a syntax error near token '("

Comment: (To your earlier question about the \ -- that is to allow line continuation -- otherwise the end of the line would just cut off the end of the command).

Comment: So, FWIW, I _do_ get your error if I (a) use bash with the above script, and (b) stuff the entire script onto a single line, with no space between the line continuation marker and the next character in the script.  Don't do that.  Paste the script in exactly as written.